# ios and mediaserverd

Tags: ios

I just read about playing media files via the browser, which in turn uses mediaserverd in iOS. Is there any place(a wiki perhaps) where I could find details about which file formats are supported by mediaserverd across various ios versions? The iOS version I'm particularly interested in, is 5.0.1, so any information would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mediaserverd daemon/process handles almost all (audio and video) media in iOS, so to answer your question, there is a long list of supported media formats/types for iOS 5.0.1 on Apple's website: http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html. There haven't been any significant changes to this list since iPhoneOS 3. Mediaserverd mostly encodes/decodes media, so the player may differ, but the core process does not.

Comment: Could you provide more info on how the mediaserverd works, perhaps some dev documentation, I'm trying to do something similar to OP.

Comment: Apple doesn't provide any documentation on this daemon, sorry.

Comment: It's a low-level process, so you're probably going to need to change your perspective on what you need for your project (this also falls out of scope for AskDifferent, so you'd have to take any additional questions over to StackOverflow).